# Integral Using Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

I think I have the following problem solved, but I'm not completely sure my reasoning is sound:

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $C$ denote the unit circle with the counterclockwise orientation. Evaluate $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{z^{n-1}}{3z^{n}-1}~dz.$$

**My attempt:** We first recall the Argument Principle:

> *Theorem.* Let $G$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma$ be a simple contour whose interior is contained in $G$. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $G$ without zeros on $\gamma$, then the number of zeros of $f$ in the interior of $\gamma$ (taking into account multiplicities) is $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}~dz.$$

In our case, we note that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{z^{n-1}}{3z^{n}-1}~dz=\frac{1}{3n}\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{nz^{n-1}}{z^{n}-\frac{1}{3}}~dz.$$ Now, $g(z)=z^{n}-\frac{1}{3}$ is an entire function (since $n>0$ by assumption) and $g\not\equiv 0$ on the unit circle $C$. Moreover, $g'(z)=nz^{n-1}$, so it follows by the Argument Principle that \begin{equation}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{nz^{n-1}}{z^{n}-\frac{1}{3}}~dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}~dz\tag{*}\end{equation}
is none other than the number of zeros of $g(z)=z^{n}-\frac{1}{3}$ in the interior of the unit circle. Counting multiplicities, there are $n$ zeros of $g$ in the interior of $C$ (namely the $n$th roots of $\frac{1}{3}$), so we conclude that the quantity in (*) is exactly $n$. Hence, $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{z^{n-1}}{3z^{n}-1}~dz=\frac{n}{3n}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

**My questions:** Does the above work look okay? I think it's right, but it felt like too simple of an argument (I know that the Argument Principle is a pretty useful tool, but still).

Thank you in advance for any comments!

Comment: I whish I was able to find an error that I could correct, but I can't.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, you could always check your solution via another method. I wonder if the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) applies here. I'll check later, my laptop's dying right now.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I initially thought about that, but I thought that the Argument Principle would be cleaner.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually, I found an error; I had originally computed the derivative of $g$ incorrectly. Does my updated argument look correct?

Comment: Yes, I was sloppy. It looks fine now.